# How can I manually bind data from a ModelStateDictionary to a presentation model with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, modelstate

I wrote an application using ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I am using a two way binding between the views and the ViewModels.

Since I am using two way binding, I get the benefit of client and server side validation which is cool. However, when I send a `POST` request to the server, and the request handler throws an exception, I want to redirect the user to the `GET` method.

When the redirect happens, I want to save the model state so that the page looks the same when I display the errors. I am able to save the state model and the errors using `ActionFilters` and `TempData` [via this approach](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-save-the-modelstate-into-session-following-the-good-practice).  However, when the request is redirected, from `POST` to `GET` the model state is saved as `System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary` object which is a key/value pair with all the user input that came from the `POST` request.

In order to present the page correctly to the end user, I need to bind the data in `System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary` to my own presentation model.

How can I bind the `System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary` object to my presentation object?

Here is how my code looks like

```
[ImportModelStateFromTempData]
public ActionResult show(int id)
{

    var prsenter = new UserProfileDetailsPresenter(id);

    ModelStateDictionary tmp = TempData["Support.ModelStateTempDataTransfer"];

    if(tmp != null)
    {
        // Some how map tmp to prsenter
    }

    return View(prsenter);

}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ExportModelStateToTempData]
public ActionResult Update(int id, DetailsPresenter model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var updater = new UpdateAddressServiceProvider(CurrentUser);

            updater.Handle(model.General);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("error", exception.Message);
    } finally
    {
        return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Show", new { Id = id }) + "#General");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's an error, don't redirect, just return the View.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ExportModelStateToTempData]
public ActionResult Update(int id, DetailsPresenter model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var updater = new UpdateAddressServiceProvider(CurrentUser);

            updater.Handle(model.General);
        }

        return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Show", new { Id = id }) + "#General");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("error", exception.Message);

        // Return the named view directly, and pass in the model as it stands.
        return View("Show", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "Show" view is expecting `UserProfileDetailsPresenter` object not `DetailsPresenter`. Instead of having to create `UserProfileDetailsPresenter` in every request, I rather redirect to the `Index` action and have it create the correct object and just bind the data.

Comment: You best bet is you make that call in both places (kudos for already having it in a method). You're going to be creating that `UserProfileDetailsPresenter` every time regardless. This is the correct way to do it in MVC. You don't want to put incorrect, malformed, or even potentially dangerous data into your database.

Comment: So in that case there is no need to ExportModelStateToTempData, right? what would be the benefit of having it?

Comment: Correct. You already have your model, so that just adds extra processing. Are you asking if there's a benefit to keeping that around?

Comment: yes. Is there any benifit of keeping `ExportModelStateToTempData` and `ImportModelStateToTempData`?

Comment: No that would be unnecessary if you aren't doing the Redirect.

Comment: Although that did not answer my question but I accepted the answer because it gave me a workaround for my problem. Thank you

Comment: This is not a good approach because if the user try reloading the page after he/she encounter and error. He/She will get an error since there is no `GET` route to match the path that they are on i.e `Profile/Update`